# Major and Minor Numbers

Tags: drivers

Can two different device drivers have same major number?

According to the resource that I have read, in the past, only major number determines the type of device driver, but now (major number + some region numbers in minor number) specifies the device driver itself.

Comment: Do you mean device *drivers* (the software that drives hardware compatibility) or device *nodes* (the items in `/dev/`)?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding the answer is no. This is an excerpt to explain this:

> Device nodes of the same type (block or character) with the same major number use the same driver.
>
> The minor number is used only by the device driver to differentiate between the different devices it may control, or how they are used. These may either be different instances of the same kind of device, (such as the first and second sound card, or hard disk partition) or different modes of operation of a given device (such as different density floppy drive media).

An example:

```
$ ls -l /dev/sda*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  0 Dec 29 06:40 /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  1 Dec 29 06:40 /dev/sda1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  2 Dec 29 06:40 /dev/sda2
```

Now each is a `block` device hence they share the same driver, here being `8`, but of course the different `minor numbers` 0, 1, and 2 to differentiate them.